# How to create 2 operations using NSOperationQueue

Tags: ios

I want to create 2 operations run simultaneously. One continually creates an object and add that to a queue at 15 ms interval. Another operation continually removes the 1st item from queue at 10 ms interval.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    _arrInformations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    queue = [NSOperationQueue new];

    // start continuous processing
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.15
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(addNewInformation)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(removeInformation)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];
}

-(void)addNewInformation {
    NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(addDataWithOperation) object:nil];
    /* Add the operation to the queue */
    [queue addOperation:operation];

}

- (void)removeInformation {
    NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(removeDataWithOperation) object:nil];
    /* Add the operation to the queue */
    [queue addOperation:operation];
    [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}

- (void) addDataWithOperation {
    NSLog(@"Add data");
    [_arrInformations addObject:@"Informations"];
}

- (void) removeDataWithOperation {
    if (_arrInformations.count) {
        [_arrInformations removeLastObject];
        [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: which approaches have you already tried?

Comment: you refer my code to the above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to use an `NSOperationQueue` to realize this functionality.  The Grand Central Dispatch and Blocks should get you the functionality that you need.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _arrInformations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   _shouldContinue = YES; // set this to NO on viewWillDisappear to stop the dispatching
   [self addNewInformation];
}

-(void)addNewInformation {
    [_arrInformations addObject:@"Informations"];
    [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
if (_shouldContinue)
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.15 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self removeInformation];
        });
}

- (void)removeInformation {
    [_arrInformations removeObject:@"Informations"];
    [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
if (_shouldContinue)
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.10 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self addInformation];
        });
}
```

You should note that calling `-reloadData` every 10-15 ms is going be *VERY* taxing on iOS performance.  You should look at `NSNotificationCenter` and `KVO` as alternative methods of *responding* to data changes, instead of causing them in a loop like this.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed I would not use `NSOperationQueue` either, but simply a couple of `NSTimer`s:

```
NSTimer *producer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.001 target:self selector:@selector(produce:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
NSTimer *consumer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.001 target:self selector:@selector(consume:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:producer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:consumer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

And then somewhere else in the code:

```
- (void) produce:(id)sender
{
    //Produce your stuff here
}

- (void) consume:(id)sender
{
    //Consume your stuff here
}
```

Or the even shorter form:

```
NSTimer *producer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(produce:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
NSTimer *consumer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(consume:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

I assign the timers to variables since I assume at some point you would like to stop the timer, that you do by sending the `invalidate` message to the instance.